# Android - Make listview fill screen and list items to fill available space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, baseadapter, android-layout-weight

So basically what I want to accomplish is make my screen be filled with a listview with exactly 4 immutable items (menu items). To do that, I created a Custom Adapter and an activity which holds a listview that uses this adapter.

Basically I want to have 4 items filling the screen, so each item should occupy 25% of the space (excluding the area for the actionbar).

I tried multiple things but none of them worked. I could make every item to have the same size (bah, easy) assigning the property `android:layout_weight="1"` and using the `android:layout_height="0dp"` to each listview item. However, the listview uses more space than the screen.

So here's what my xml files look like now:

**item_menu.xml** (listview item)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context="com.android.franzoni.atlas.views.CatalogActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMenuIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_profile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMenuTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgMenuIcon"
    android:text="Menu Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_menu.xml** (Activity's layout)

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="com.android.franzoni.atlas.views.MenuActivity" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Do you guys have any clue how do to that? Is there an easier way to do a menu activity? (I thought about listview because I am going to handle the swipe and click events)

Comment: If you have fixed 4 items you can try adding them to LinearLayout that will make things much easier

Comment: Well, I don't know if I get it, but I am using a Linear Layout for the ListView, does the fact that my custom item uses a RelativeLayout affects it? I need the RelativeLayout because the Item would have an Image centered with a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out that the best way to do it for now is to set the layout programmatically, calling a method to get the Display Size and then setting the layout height based on that.

```
// Get Screen Size
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
context.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics (metrics);

// Set layout based on screen size and qty of items
ll.LayoutParameters.Height = (metrics.HeightPixels - topbarSize) / items.Count ;
```